# unable to run ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an 2.2 android  project that I want to add the ActionBarSherlock.
When I run my project I get this error;

```
C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:183: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:spinnerMode'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:258: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:animationResolution'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:85: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:328: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error 
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:117: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:196: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:197: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:198: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dialog'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:222: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:223: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
[2012-11-09 13:54:53 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:43 - testApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:258: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:animationResolution'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:85: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:328: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:102: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:106: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:117: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-11-09 14:05:55 - testApp] C:\Users\vitaly\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

source found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.
    [2012-11-09 14:11:12 - testApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
    [2012-11-09 14:20:55 - testApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

and problem with xml fragment_sample.xml the error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Element type "xmlns:android" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" 
     or "/>".
    - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix :
```

and the  fragment_sample.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android:name="com.test.sherlock.SherlockSimpleFragment"
android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 9):

When you are using Action bar Sherlock in your project make sure,

Step 1:

your are building a project which is an android version 4.0 or later. To check whether you are building 4.0 or later goto,
    properties -> android -> check project build path to 4.0 or later versions.

Step 2:

Clean your project

This should solve your problem.

Comment: You cannot clean your project in Android Studio.  That was only a feature in Eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

You probably trying to build the project with the wrong Android SDK version. Try building it with 4.1 (API lvl 16). You can change it in Eclipse in the project properties -> Android tab.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the xml is malformed. There are a few things going on here.

You do not specify what type of view you want, and so it is taking `xmlns:android` as the element (view) type. This confuses the parser, because an element cannot be equal to anything (ie. an element cannot be equal to a url).

Then it complains that you haven't declared the namespace (because it used up  then trying to declare an element as equal to something).

Finally, it looks like the first element isn't closed.

Correcting it should be as simple as creating a proper element/view type before setting the namespace, and then making sure that all elements are terminated properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android:name="com.test.sherlock.SherlockSimpleFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</SomeLayout>
```

It looks like the intention was for `SomeLayout` to be a `LinearLayout`, however it could be any type of layout, since you are just using it as a container, I would guess you would want `FrameLayout`, however there are good reasons for picking other types of layout.

Some other points not related to the question.

- `android:orientation` is only used in a `LinearLayout`
- You do not need to specify a weight on the view because you are using match parent. You would only need to use it if the wrapping element were a `LinearLayout`, and you were trying to make the view occupy a percentage of the screen.
- Because this layout is pretty simple, you could also attach the fragment directly to its parent layout