# ActionBarSherlock IcsSpinner in Android 2.2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I tried to implement ActionBarSherlock project into my ohter Android 2.2 project. Only thing i need is to use IcsSpinner and its value of "android:spinnerMode". While importing whole ActionBarSherlock project, I get lot of errors like:

```
[2013-09-30 09:04:56 - AppGlobal] C:\Users\User\Downloads\ActionBarSherlock-4.0.0\ActionBarSherlock-4.0.0\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:166: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
```

anyone faced same problem? I have support library in my app project included, in library project there is used Android 4.0. I get the same problem even when I change Android in AB Sherlock library to 2.2...

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android project *and* the ABS project both needs to be compiled with an SDK >= 4.0

Go to

> Properties > Android > Project build target

and choose an SDK with an API level of at least 14.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308127).

Comment: so minSDK can be set to 4 and still users with Android 2.1 can run this application?

Comment: Yes, the minSdk version is not affected by the compile SDK version.